# Doubts in NSNotification in Swift

Tags: swift

I am developing my very first app for iOS and not understanding notifications.

I am sending notifications as:

```
DefaultCenter.postNotificationName("evRodadaAtualizei", object: nil)
```

In another class, I have a method that observes this notification:

```
DefaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("Atualizar"), 
    name: "evRodadaAtualizei", object: nil)
```

My question is:

This observer will listen any notification with that name? It is not important the class where notification was declared? In other words, is possible to have a place to put all the notifications (like a notification library), because all of them are independent of the class?

If I am understanding correctly, this is very different of the concept of events in C# or VB.Net where events belongs to classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notifications in Cocoa work inter-class. It doesn't matter where the notification is created or observed.

However, note the `object` parameter on the `postNotificationName` method. If set, this should correspond to the object posting the notification. If you only want to observe notifications for a given object, set the object parameter to that object when you add the observer. e.g.

```
class MyObjectClass {

   func doSomething() {
      // Do something and then notify

      DefaultCenter.postNotificationName("evRodadaAtualizei", object: self)
   }
}

class MyObserverClass {

    func startProcess() {

        var myObject = MyObjectClass()

        DefaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("Atualizar"), name: "evRodadaAtualizei", object: myObject)
    }

    func Atualizar() {

    }

}
```

Comment: The compiler only need the name of notification to link them (sender and observer will use the same name in respective methods), or I need to declare this notification somewhere (`var evRodadaAtualizei = NSNotification()`)? If so, sometimes could be hard to debug, since someplace the name of notification could have misspelled name and the compiler have no idea that happened, is that right?

Comment: Correct, the only thing linking them is the name. No need to declare it - although to save typos it's good practice to declare the name as a constant string.

Comment: Great. Using constants will avoid the problem I mentioned before

Comment: So other people don't rip their hair out like I did – Your observer class has to be of type NSObject, or it won't be able to receive notifications.